Flutter Build failed for sqflite_android
When i run my flutter project for my phone, i get this error (which i hadn't before updating android studio & other things like flutter & dependencies) :
Launching lib/main.dart on moto e40 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/user/Documents/programmation/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /home/user/Downloads/rpms/archives/android-studio.new/jbr/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i tried several things, including :

deleting ~/.graddle/caches
deleting ~/.graddle
deleting ~/.pub-cache
switching back to the old android studio version
pub remove / add sqflite
...


It may be a mismatch and configuration issue with your gradle and Android SDK. I recommend to open the "android" folder of the Flutter project with Android Studio and let the IDE to build the gradle. If there is any conflict, it will show you the exact error in the build message section.

android studio is happy with my graddle, no error whatsoever. iI just get this warning before building : Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

neverming, i managed to get rid of that warning by updating android sdk to api35

Solved it by updating
id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
to
id "com.android.application" version "8.7.2" apply false
in android/settings.graddle
android studio didn't told me there was a newer version
(got that info here)

This has worked for me when I have tried to update my project from android 33 or lower to android 34 for my earlier flutter project
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions (if project show too many outdated dependencies)
update android/app/build.gradle as below please find android 34 mig in below file changes


android {

    // android 34 mig => added
    namespace = "packagename" 
    compileSdkVersion 34

    // android 34 mig => removed
/*
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
*/

    // android 34 mig => added
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"



update android/setting.gradle as below please find android 34 mig in below file changes


// android 34 mig => updated all file

pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
//    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"



update android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties as below please find android 34 mig in below file changes


// android 34 mig => updated or new version
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip



Update android/build.gradle android 34 mig and find


buildscript {
// android 34 mig => updated or new version
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'



And then try below commands
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

The files you mentionned already have the changes you mentionned. I tried changing things anyway, but it didn't work.

@michelduturfu Try these steps, Update your sqflite dependancy - (if not up to date), Check if mismatch or corruption in the JDK image is found, or Check if mismatch between the JDK version and the Android Gradle plugin is found

@tech_ramakant Wen i flutter update, there are 17 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints. but none are sqflite.
I don't know how to check for mismatch, but android studio seem happy. (no err).
The only thing is in android/settings.graddle, the is def properties = new Properties() and android studio say it Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties' but this error was already there in previous compiling versions.

@michelduturfu It’s possible that the issue arises from differences in Android Studio versions. I’m using:
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2
(Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12169540, built on August 1, 2024).
You can try creating a new default Flutter project (counter_app) and check its android/settings.gradle file. Update your project's settings.gradle accordingly to match the new default project's template

I created a new empty project (the counter app) and it compiles perfectly. But there is no differences between the graddle files. Maybe it's a sqflite issue.

I added the sqflite dependencie in the new empty project and now it doesn't compile anymore... The issue is either sqflite or corrupted cached files on my computer.
